# What's creating huge gaps between my mobile menu items?

Tags: html, ios, css, menu, responsive

I have created a hamburger mobile menu and for some reason there are unwanted gaps between the links there.

```css
  @media only screen and (max-width: 440px) {
  .elementor-nav-menu a {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .mobilemenucontact {
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #mobilemenucontact {
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    .makeSmall {
      font-size: 95%;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    .email-mobile {
      width: 28px;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    .facebook-mobile {
      width: 28px;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    .column-contact {
      padding: 5px 30px;
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    .mobilenumber {
      color: #142c7c !important
    }
  }
  .active {
    border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff;
    padding: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
  }
```

```html
<p class="makeSmall" style="text-align: center;">
  <a href="mailto:maya@mayabarber.co.il"><img class="email-mobile" src="http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Untitled-1.svg" width="33" height="33" /></a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/mayabarbercontrolcenter/"><img class="facebook-mobile" src="http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Untitled-2.svg" width="33" height="33" /></a>
  <label style="color: #61f6ff;" data-mce-fragment="1"> | <a class="mobilenumber" style="color: #001a71;" href="tel:052-6582643" data-mce-fragment="1">052-6582643</a></label></p>
```

I want it to be just in one line, and to look like this on all phone devices:
[image]

I used to have some issues with Safari and iPhonems when attempting to make it look fine. Here's the website link if you wanna inspect: [www.mayabarber.co.il](http://www.mayabarber.co.il)
Any ideas? 
I can replace the CSS and HTML if necessary.

Comment: Why don't you just set `.elementor-nav-menu a: { display: inline-block; }` on every viewport width?

Comment: Because this hamburger menu only displays on mobiles so it's irrelevant to other widths.

Comment: And yet the inline-block thing created gaps among the different elements and I can't see why

Comment: You have `.elementor-nav-menu a, .elementor-nav-menu a:focus, .elementor-nav-menu a:hover { padding: 10px 20px; }` - that creates padding between icons. I presume, that is what you mean by _unwanted gaps_.

Comment: For some reason I can't see where this CSS is attached too. It's not directly in the menu I have posted here. Weird.

Comment: Anyways I've override it with !important for screens below 768px width, thanks!

Comment: You can inspect any element in devtools - it shows where applied rules are located. That `padding` is in `frontend.min.css?ver=2.0.11` in this case.

Comment: Thanks! I think it worked. I wish there was a way to make sure it works on iPhones with safari browsers. When I inspect it seems fine but it's not always accurate.

Comment: You don't need to add a new *@media query* for every element you want to style. Instead use it once for every width and put everything applicable inside the brackets.